# Splitting multiline string into groups based on a regex pattern

Tags: regex

I have a multiline string that I want to split wherever a new line starts with a digit.

So this:

```
1:53|18
-:
-:
R:
-:
R:
-:24|18
-:
-:
R:
-:
-:
R:
-:
-:
L:
-:
L:49|1
-:
-:
-:
2:44|18
L:
L:
2:45|16
-:
-:
-:
-:
```

Becomes this:

```
Group 1:
    1:53|18
    -:
    -:
    R:
    -:
    R:
    -:24|18
    -:
    -:
    R:
    -:
    -:
    R:
    -:
    -:
    L:
    -:
    L:49|1
    -:
    -:
    -:
    
Group 2:
    2:44|18
    L:
    L:
    
Group 3:
    2:45|16
    -:
    -:
    -:
    -:
```

I am trying to build a regex that will match each group, but am having difficulties with either capturing too little (because of newline issues) or capturing too much.

The best I could do is: ^\d.(\n|.)*?  (https://regex101.com/r/I1q7Xl/1)

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try `^\d.*(?:\r?\n(?!\d).*)*` https://regex101.com/r/q0XJ6O/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can match the line that starts with a digit, followed by matching all lines that do not start with a digit using a negative lookahead if that is supported.

```
^\d.*(?:\r?\n(?!\d).*)*
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `\d.*` Match a digit and the rest of the line
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\r?\n(?!\d).*` Match a newline and the rest of the line if it does not start with a digit
- `)*` Close group and repeat 0+ times

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/q0XJ6O/1)

Comment: Thank you. This is perfect. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can split the string on (zero-width) matches of the following regular expression.

```
rgx = /(?m)^(?<!\A)(?=\d)/
```

[Start your engine](https://regex101.com/r/jy9kBk/3/)

The required code depends on the language being used, of course. With Ruby, for example, it would be:

```
str.split(rgx)
  #=> ["1:53|18\n-:\n-:\nR:\n-:\nR:\n-:24|18\n-:\n-:\nR:\n-:\n-:\nR:\n-:\n-:\nL:\n-:\nL:49|1\n-:\n-:\n-:\n",
  #    "2:44|18\nL:\nL:\n",
  #    "2:45|16\n-:\n-:\n-:\n-:"]
```

The regex engine (I used PCRE at the link) performs the following operations.

```
(?m)     : invoke multine mode, causing '^' and '$' to match the beginning and
           end of lines 
^        : match beginning of line
(?<!\A)  : negative lookbehind asserts that current position is not
         : at the beginning of the string
(?=\d)   : positive lookahead asserts current position is followed by a digit
```

The the negative lookbehind `(?<!\A)` prevents there being a match at the beginning of the string. Without that some languages would return an array whose first element is an empty string.

Unlike other regex engines, `(?m)` causes Ruby's regex engine to invoke *single-line* or *DOTALL* mode, which results in `.` matching all characters, including line terminators. That is not wanted. Ruby always interprets `^` and `$` as matching the beginning and end of lines, however, so `(?m)` should not be included in the regex when using Ruby. Nor does Ruby require the negative lookbehind `(?<!\A)`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have gone with the first answer as I found it easier to understand, but that is my limitation, not yours. I found your answer very informative.